# didSelectItemAt() is not loading my viewController

Tags: ios, swift4

### First viewController

```
   import UIKit

  class photosCollectionViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var photoCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    photoCollectionView.delegate = self
    photoCollectionView.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

var photosArray = PhotoClass(Name:["Dog","Cat","Lion","Tiger"])
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photosArray.Name.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let photocell = photoCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photosCell", for: indexPath) as! photoscollectionCell
    //photocell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    photocell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: photosArray.Name[indexPath.row])
    photocell.cellLabel.text = photosArray.Name[indexPath.row]

    return photocell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Something")
    let  vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photosDetails") as! detailsCollectionViewController
   // vc.descriptionLabel.text = "Animals"

}
}
```

didSelectItemAt() is not loading  my detailsCollectionViewController,but while i am  selecting the cell it's calling .so where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You don't do `self.present(vc, animated: true)`? Because for now, you just instantiated the view controller.

Comment: How automatically it will call your didSelectItemAt() method if you don't select the cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write this if you want to push :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Something")
    let  vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photosDetails") as! detailsCollectionViewController
   // vc.descriptionLabel.text = "Animals"
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

It may helps to you.Thank you

Comment: thank you Sanjukta ,you save my day .last two days i was struggling for this how to add Navigation controller

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Something")
    let  vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photosDetails") as! detailsCollectionViewController
   // vc.descriptionLabel.text = "Animals"
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
```